# Reference to formGroup field in template

Tags: angular

In a template I use:

```html
  <form [formGroup]="rightForm">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="right" required formControlName="right">
    <div [hidden]="rightForm.get('right')!.valid || rightForm.get('right')!.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
      <div *ngIf="rightForm.get('right')!.errors?.['required']">
        name is empty!
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

to get the reference to the child control right I have to use

```
rightForm.get('right')!
```

This is very cumbersome. Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use rightForm.value(maybe pass it ngSubmit) it should give you the object of all the form controls and their respective values.